# Styling HTML table elements to have thicker parts of borders affected by colspan and rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

Basically, my table looks something like this:

```
______________________________________________________
|____|___________|___________|___________|___________|
|    |__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
|____|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
|    |__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
|____|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
|    |__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
|____|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
```

And I would like it to have more impact on what belongs where with thicker lines (the lines that are shown with the arrows):

```
 _____v___________v___________v___________v___________v
|____|___________|___________|___________|___________|
 |    |__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
|____|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
 |    |__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
|____|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
 |    |__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
|____|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
```

Is it possible to make those lines thicker without having to write a Javascript function that finds out for each cell if it needs border thickening on one of its sides?

Comment: Just add a table border and th,td borders: `table: {border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;} th,td {border: 5px solid black;}`

Comment: To affect just those affected by `colspan`/`rowspan`, include those in the selector. `td[rowspan], td[colspan], th[rowspan], td[rowspan] { border: 5px solid }`

Comment: This is not what I meant, I need the specific horizontal and vertical lines showed by arrows on my post to be thicker, not border of the cells that have the colspan/rowspan attribute.

Comment: You want the thick lines along cells that happen to be in certain columns but do not have the `colspan` attribute themselves. In that case you will need to apply some kind of scripting, as this kind of formatting is not possible with CSS alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, without JavaScript this seems to be undoable. Here is a short script demonstrating how a *script* could do the job.

The array `nums` defines the format of the table to be generated: `[row-groups, rows-per-groups, col-groups, cols-per-group]`. Both the generating function `mktable()` and the line-decorator function `tbllines()` refer to the same `nums` array:

```js
const tbl=document.querySelector('table'), nums=[3,2,5,4]
tbl.innerHTML=mktable(...nums);
tbllines(tbl,...nums);

function tbllines(tbl,n1,n2,m1,m2){
[...tbl.children[0].children].forEach((r,i)=>{
  let cols=[...r.children];
  if (i) // as of second row:
    cols.forEach((c,j)=>{
      if (i%n2==1) c.classList.add("top")
      if (j%m2==[i%n2==1?1:0]) c.classList.add("left");
    });
  else   // header row:
    cols.forEach((c,j)=>{
      if (j) c.className="left";
    });
})
}
  
function mktable(n1,n2,m1,m2){
 return '<tr>'
+[['<td></td>'].concat(Array(m1).fill('<td colspan="'+m2+'"></td>')).join('')]
    .concat(Array(n1*n2).fill(Array(m1*m2).fill('<td></td>')).map((r,i)=>[i%n2?'':'<td rowspan="'+n2+'"></td>'].concat(r).join(''))).join('</tr>\n<tr>')+'</tr>';
}
```

```css
td {width:20px; height:20px; border:1px solid grey}
td.left {border-left: 2px solid blue}
td.top  {border-top: 2px solid blue}
```

```html
<table></table>
```